# Change feature name in gate document with JAPE or Groovy

Tags: gate

I have a GATE document like that:

[image]

I need to change the name of a feature in the annotation. Here i need to change `type`by `category`

Is it possible to do that with a JAPE rule or Groovy script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, either.  A JAPE rule is probably the simplest:

```
Phase: RenameFeature
Input: Mention
Options: control = all

Rule: Rename
({Mention}):mention
-->
:mention {
  for(Annotation a : mentionAnnots) {
    a.getFeatures().put("category", a.getFeatures().remove("type"));
    // note Map.remove returns the value we just removed
  }
}
```

Inside a RHS Java block labelled with `:label` the variable `labelAnnots` is an `AnnotationSet` containing the annotations that were matched by the label on the LHS.  In this case there's only one of them but the `for` loop is still the most convenient way to access the individual `Annotation` from the set.